# typeorm SQLITE_BUSY:database is locked

Tags: typeorm, node-sqlite3

I'm using multiple processes to write and read to an sqlite DB and am running into a busy error:Error: SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked.

Then I try to set the `enableWAL` parameter to true and the `busyErrorRetry` parameter to 300 milliseconds. Finally,When the problem occurs again,SQLITE_BUSY error will not be reported at this time,But the sqlite database seems to be locked.I don't know if retries are too frequent, which aggravates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the retry parameter busyErrorRetry is not a good behavior.I want to use the `PRAGMA busy_timeout =` parameter, but typeomr does not support it.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting additonal information as answer.